# What mechanism makes Python lambdas work without await keyword?

Tags: python, lambda, async-await, python-asyncio

I just noticed something surprising. Consider the following example:

```
import asyncio

async def wait_n(n):
    asyncio.sleep(n)

async def main(fn):
    print("meh")
    await fn(1)
    print("foo")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(wait_n))
```

When we run this, we rightfully receive the following warning:

```
awaitable_lambda.py:5: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
```

asyncio.sleep(n)

This is because in `wait_n` we called `asyncio.sleep(n)` without `await`.

But now consider the second example:

```
import asyncio

async def main(fn):
    print("meh")
    await fn(1)
    print("foo")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(lambda n: asyncio.sleep(n)))
```

This time we are using a `lambda` and surprisingly the code works just fine even though there is no `await`.

I understand that we **can not** use `await` inside a Python `lambda` expression so this seems like a feature to improve ergonomics but it leads to me some questions:

1. How exactly does this work? Does this simple "inject" an `await` before any coroutine function?
2. Is this documented somewhere (PEP)?
3. Are there any other implications of this? Can we just safely call coroutinefunctions from lambda expressions and rely on Python to await things for us?

Comment: in the first snippet change ```async def wait_n(n):
    asyncio.sleep(n)``` to ```def wait_n(n):
    return asyncio.sleep(n)``` and you get exact equialent to lambda, which shows what lambda is def with implicit return

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any asynchronous function returns an [*awaitable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable). You don't need to "`await` the function call" immediately, you just need to `await` the returned awaitable value eventually. I.e., these two are equivalent:

```
await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

```
awaitable = asyncio.sleep(1)
await awaitable
```

As such, it should be easy to see that the call `fn(1)` of the lambda (implicitly) returns an awaitable, and `await` awaits it. The `async def wait_n` on the other hand never returns the `sleep` awaitable and never awaits it itself.

As a corollary example of this, if you have any wrapper around an `async` function, there's not necessarily a need for that wrapper to be `async` itself:

```
def add_1(func):
    def wrapper(a):
        return func(a + 1)  # passes the awaitable return value through

    return wrapper

@add_1
async def foo(a):
    await asyncio.sleep(a)

async def main():
    await foo(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no async lambdas in Python.

Consider:

`f = lambda n: asyncio.sleep(n)`

Here:

```
callable(f)
```

is True. But

```
asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f)
```

is False. So f is a function, but not a coroutine function (not an async function).

What happens is that

```
x = f()
```

gets called immediately. But it returns in the result of `asyncio.sleep(n)`, which is a corountine object (not yet a call to sleep -- that won't happened until you `await x`.

Its somewhat like this:

```
async def g():
   print("g")
   await asyncio.sleep(n)
print(type(g))    # function
print(type(g()))  # coroutine, (g not printed)
# ----
def f():  # This is like your lambda, but with a print statement
   print("f")
   return asyncio.sleep(n)

print(type(f))  # function
print("- 1")
x = f()  # Prints f immediately
print("- 2")
print(type(x))  # coroutine
await x         # Sleeps
print("Done")
```

Note, because coroutines are "things to be executed and produce a value when awaited", you have control over their execution by deciding when to call await:

```
async def f(s):
   print(s)
   return s


a = f("world")
b = f("hello")
x = await b  # prints hello
y = await a  # prints world
print(x,y)   # prints hello world
```