# How can I know if a lambda is an coroutine function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

TIL that you can use lambda to call coroutine functions. You don't even have to add await in the lambda. Great! (Using Python 10).

But... although the lambda can be awaited (after being called), it doesn't seem to be an     `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(...)`:

```
import asyncio

async def f(*args):
    print("F yeah!", args)

async def run():
    f2 = lambda : f(123)
    await f2()        # "F yeah!", (123) printed.
    # So ... f2 is a coroutine function like f?
    # Let's find out.
    print(type(f))   # function
    print(type(f()))  # coroutine
    print(type(f2))   # function
    print(type(f2())) # coroutine
    assert asyncio.iscoroutine(f())        # Yes
    assert asyncio.iscoroutine(f2())       # Yes
    assert asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f)  # Yes
    assert asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f2) # Fail!

    # No. f2 is not like f
    
asyncio.run(run())
```

What magic is happening here? Is the lambda a coroutine function or not?

Because of this, I can't easily write:

```
def wrapper(coroOrFunc, *args, **kw):
   if asyncio.iscoroutine(coroOrFunc):           return await coroOrFunc
   elif asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(coroOrFunc): return await coroOrFunc(*args, **kw)
   else callable(coroOrFunc):                    return coroOrFunc(*args, **kw)
```

... as I'll be sad because `wrapper(f2)` sees a callable, not an `iscoroutinefunction`.
A sad thing for decorators.

Related: [What mechanism makes Python lambdas work without await keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56833112/what-mechanism-makes-python-lambdas-work-without-await-keyword)

Comment: The `lambda` is not a coroutine, but that lambda calls a coroutine that returns a waitable result.  You're not really awaiting `f2`.  You're awaiting what `f2` returned, which happens to be the result of an `async` function.

Comment: But is it a "coroutine function"? When called it returns a coroutine, so it seems like a coroutine function. But iscoroutinefunction(f) -> True,  iscoroutinefunction(f2) -> False.

Comment: Oops -- fixed question to make it clear.

Comment: “what type does this Python function return when called” is undecidable in general

Comment: Try adding `def g(*args):` / `return f(234)`.  You'll find it behaves the same way.  `g` is not a coroutine, but it returns an awaitable result, so you can say `await g()`.  The async magic is not that the function is a coroutine, but that it returns an awaitable result.

Comment: Also, you can’t write that `wrapper` function even if you have access to a magic `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction`. The correct way to write it (with no `await`, because it’s not an async function) probably isn’t as useful as you were imagining.

Comment: You can try `f2._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine` and then `print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f2))` but it's ugly hack.

Comment: Oh good point. Lambdas really *are never* coroutine functions:  `f2 = lambda : print(Made it here); f(123)`  immediately prints and returns a coroutine.  Whomp, whomp.

Answer (score -1):

The magic happening here is due to the introduction of the "coroutine call syntax" in Python 3.7 and later. This syntax allows you to call a coroutine function as if it were a regular function, and it returns a coroutine object. In Python 3.10, this syntax was extended to work with lambdas as well.

Here's a breakdown of what's happening in your code:

1. You define a coroutine function f.
2. You create a lambda `f2` that calls `f(123)` when invoked.
3. When you call await `f2()`, it behaves as if you're awaiting a coroutine, and it works as expected.

However, despite this behavior, `f2` is still just a regular function (not a coroutine function) and doesn't show up as a coroutine function when you check its type or use `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()`.

So, in summary, the lambda `f2` can be used to call coroutine functions, but it doesn't itself become a coroutine function. This behavior is a consequence of the coroutine call syntax introduced in Python 3.7 and later.

Comment: Is this generated text? There’s no such thing as “coroutine call syntax”.

Comment: That is exactly why I put it in double quotes. I meant that after Python 3.7 what python returns on coroutine functions has changed. Partially answering your first comment to the Original Post too.